# How to add a string into each and every string in an array by using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript

I want to add "*." at opening and ";" at ending on each array element. Below is the sample code.

```
var ext = getExt(filename);
var s = '<%=AllowedExtensions %>';
var match = s.split(', ');
```

In the above code in 'match' I use to get ["jpg", "png", "txt"] like this. So here on each array element I want to prefix with "*." and at end of each want to add ";" and also it should give me a string such as "*.jpg;*.png;*.txt;" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var matchString = '.' + match.join(';.') + ';'
```

Answer (score 1):

ES5 code:

```
match = match.map(function( word ) {
    return '*.' + word + ';';
}).join('');
```

ES3 code:

```
for(var i = 0, len = match.length; i < len; i++) {
    match[ i ] = '*.' + match[ i ] + ';';
}

match = match.join('');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PNDr6/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
for(var k = 0; k < match.length; k++)
{
    match[k] = '*.' + match[k];
}
var allExten = match.join(';');
```